# Dynamic drivers

Tags: drivers

Is there a way for a driver that is set up to reference a material so that it can be used be used across different materials cloned from the initial driver? So that if I have Material001, which effects itself, then copy it and set it to a unique instance Material002, have the driver automatically set up to rerence this new instance instead of the old?

[image]